# Azure runtime error from Swagger and CastleWindsor

Tags: c#, .net, azure, target-framework

I'm having a problem with a deployed application. I'll try and provide as much information as possible.

The api project makes use of both Swagger via Swashbuckle and Castle Windsor.

When Swagger is enabled in SwaggerConfig.cs via 

`[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]`

We get the following exception:

`` Method not found: 'Void Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsConfig.RootUrl(System.Func`2<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,System.String>)'. ``

Here's the full Register call, in case it's relevant

```cs
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.RootUrl(req => req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/api");
                c.MultipleApiVersions((api, v) => true,
                vc =>
                {
                    vc.Version("mobile", "Mobile");
                    vc.Version("web", "Web");
                });
                c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
                c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
                c.DocumentFilter<VersionFilter>();
            })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                c.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();
            });
```

If we disable swagger (by removing the assembly attribute) the application then starts failing on Castle Windsor startup with the following error:

`Method 'Create' in Type 'XXX.XXX.XXX.CastleWindsor.WindsorCompositionRoot' from assembly 'xxx.xxx.Backend, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.'`

Here's the Configure() method for WindsorConfig.cs

```cs
public static void Configure()
    {
        WindsorConfig.Container = new WindsorContainer();
        WindsorConfig.Container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorCompositionRoot(WindsorConfig.Container));
    }
```

The issue occurred when we upgraded a shared library in the solution to .net standard 2 from a PCL. This in turn meant we had to upgrade all of the other projects in the solution to .net 4.7.1 (there is a UWP app in the solution which was our original upgrade target which meant we had to upgrade the library, but I digress), so to summarize, this issue occurred on a 4.7.1 upgrade.

The application is deployed to Azure via Bamboo w/ msbuild & msdeploy. We're confident the binaries and web.config are in sync with development as we've manually deployed those via FTP to be sure.
I deleted all binaries via FTP before re-uploading to make sure that there were no legacy assemblies.

I have verified the Azure app in Kudu is showing the correct versions to have 4.7.1 support as documented here: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/63

The app that is not running is deployed into a virtual directory (/api) of the app service in Azure. The primary website (on /) is static and uses angular to access the API.

I have confirmed that the web.config in both the / and /api projects are showing

`<compilation targetFramework="4.7.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />`

Package versions are as follows (we have performed a nuget reinstall following the target framework upgrade):

  `<package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles" version="0.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />`

I had this problem previously on the development environment when I attempted to upgrade to 4.7.1 (for another dependency) but this time around development is working without error and it is only now failing when deployed to Azure.
.net framework version in azure portal for this app service shows 4.7

Right now, I'm thinking the problem is not actually the code we're using to initialize Swagger and/or Castle Windsor, it's more likely related to a framework version or mismatched assembly version, since the app is running on my development machine without error, but I've run out of ideas of what to try next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this issue https://forums.asp.net/t/2137242.aspx by searching for the Windsor error, `System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator` failing to instantiate with the error `Method 'Create' in type 'MyType' from assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.`

That lead me to checking `System.Net.Http` versions that were deployed. `System.Net.Http` was `4.2.0.0` locally and this DLL was deployed to Azure, but it looks like a different version was actually being used by the runtime.

What's weird is that when I deleted the deployed version of System.Net.Http from the bin folder, the error said: `'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` so this is the version of the assembly that Azure was providing regardless of the version in the bin folder (also 4.2.0.0).

I added a binding redirect for System.Net.Http and the application now starts up normally

`<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>`